# Daniel 10:20 and the prince of Grecia

Tags: prophecy, daniel, apocalyptic

In Daniel 10:20 who is the prince the text refers to when it states the prince of Grecia shall come?

> Dan 10:20 - “Do you know why I have come to you?” he said. “I must
> return at once to fight against the prince of Persia, and when I have
> gone forth, behold, the prince of Greece will come.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group and contributing a question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: A *prince* of the "angelic" realm is being referenced here. See also **Dan, 10:13**, which also speaks of *battles* within the "angelic" realm. + 1.

Answer (score 1):

This verse is surely looking forward to the opening of the next chapter, in which the ruler of Persia gets into a fight with Greece, and a mighty king arises whose dominion, after his death, is divided into four parts. That story can be easily understood as a reference to the career of the "Greek" ruler Alexander the Great, who overwhelmed the Persians, and whose kingdom was famously divided after his death.

The message of the verse appears to be that the angel will be fighting alongside Alexander in the campaign against the Persians. In fact Alexander will come once the angel is ready to "go forth" and play his own part.

Comment: Not only **Dan, 10:20** but also **Dan, 10:13** speaks of the *good* and *bad* of the angelic realm. Mesmerizing! + 1.

Answer (score 1):

This "prince" is not a physical ruler, but a spiritual guardian. This is clarified by by reading the verses in context:

> As I looked up, I saw a man dressed in linen with a belt of fine gold
> around his waist. 6 His body was like chrysolite, his face shone like
> lightning, his eyes were like fiery torches, his arms and feet looked
> like burnished bronze, and the sound of his voice was like the roar of
> a multitude....12 “Do not fear, Daniel,” he continued; “from the first
> day you made up your mind to acquire understanding and humble yourself
> before God, your prayer was heard. Because of it I started out, 13 but
> the prince of the kingdom of Persia stood in my way for twenty-one
> days, until finally Michael, one of the chief princes, came to help
> me. I left him there with the prince of the kingdom of Persia... Soon I must fight the prince of Persia again. When I leave, the prince of Greece will come; 21 but I shall tell you what is written in the book of truth. No one supports me against these except Michael, your prince...

The identity of the unnamed glorious "man" is controversial: some same it is God or the Angel of the Lord, others say Jesus or an archangel other than Michael. Whoever it is, Michael helps him fight against the "prince" of Persia. That has already happened, but the the "prince" of Greece will follow. This is a prophecy that after Persia is defeated (leading to the Jews' return to Jerusalem) the Greeks will come and oppress the Jews again, especially under the reign of Antiochus IV, who infamously defiled the Temple and banned essential elements of the Jewish religion.

**Conclusion**: This chapter deals with the potentates of the spiritual realm, later called "archangels," Michael being specifically named as the guardian prince of Israel. It is a matter of opinion whether the spiritual princes of Persia and Greece were understood by the author as their guardian angels, their warrior gods (see footnote to v. 13 [here](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2010&version=NABRE)), or demons.

Comment: Seeing as I made a couple of comments here before your answer, I feel compelled to say something about this answer. This chapter deals with 4 angelic princes (leaders), of whom only one is named, i.e. Michael, although the objective cases of *I*, i.e. the two 'me's, in **Dan, 10:13**, are most likely, according to many learned theologians, in ref to Gabriel, who we know to be subordinate to Michael, as are all other angels. Now, the bible "canon" speaks of only one archangel, namely Michael. The non canonical book of **Enoch**, however, speaks to a plethora of archangels, but is non verifiable